# Storing Staff and Customer interactions in a database

Tags: database-design

I want to design a database where I can record any interactions between Staff and Customer regarding a Car that might be sold. The interactions could be test drive or enquiry about the car. I was wondering how we could store these interactions since a customer can have many interactions with many staff members. [This](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/erdiagram-120903114213-phpapp02/95/how-to-draw-an-effective-er-diagram-46-728.jpg?cb=1346676863) is what my ER diagram looks like currently. Here, this design will represent the staff and customer involved in the sale of the Product(car).

Comment: OK and what's your question?

Comment: I am confused if I should have interactions as a relation or as an Entity with staff, customer and Car entity connected to it?

Comment: Do interactions have their own attributes that are independent of cars, customers or staff? If so, then interactions should be a separate entity.